# Dropdown icon has disappeared after upgrade to Angular 16/Bootstrap 5

Tags: angular, dropdown, bootstrap-5

Below Angular code is used to display a Dropdown with list of Car brands.

```
<dropdown [items]="carList" [selected]="selCar" (select)="carSelect($event)">
</dropdown>
```

This was displayed correctly with a little arrow-down icon. This was with Angular 14 and Bootstrap 4.
After upgrading to Angular 16 and Bootstrap 5 the icon is missing. The function is the same.
Both the old and new version has the same generated HTML code (via F12 in browser):

```
<dropdown>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
  </select>
</dropdown>
```

If I change the class to "form-select" the correct icon appears.
The question is how do I implement that in my code since the "<select..." part is generated by Angular?
I tried adding the "<select..." part in my Angular file but it was ignored.
I tried to add "form-select" to the "<dropdown..." part and then the icon appeared but as a separate part of the dropdown and without function.

Comment: what is "dropdown"? thre're dozen of libraries that have a dropdown control. Futhermore you can create your own dropdown component. Can you edit your question and indicate what library are you using or the dropdown component?

Comment: My bad, I thought '<dropdown>' was a standard component. It turned out to be a component our resource team has created. The icon was easy to get back as long as I know where to look. Thanks for pointing me in right direction. 
The solution was to replace 'form-control' with 'form-select'.